# Evento KeyDown + Enter. Limpar buffer do teclado

Tags: c#, buffer

Criei um WinForm C# .net de exemplo contendo `textbox1`, `textbox2` e `button1` para simular a seguinte situação:

Ao iniciar a aplicação, o `textbox1` recebe o foco e quando pressionamos <kbd>Enter</kbd>, foi programado seu evento `KeyDown` para que o foco passe para o `textbox2`.

Acontece também que dentro do mesmo `KeyDown` do `textbox1` deve ser executado algum tipo de processamento, que no meu exemplo é representado por um `Thread.Slepp(5000)`.

O problema ocorre quando pressionamos várias vezes o <kbd>Enter</kbd> no `textbox1`. Ele executa várias vezes o processamento desse `KeyDown` quando o esperado era de que executasse do `textbox1` e passasse o foco para o `textbox2`.

Aparentemente ele armazena algum tipo de *buffer* do teclado, disparando várias vezes o evento do `textbox` selecionado.

Alguma sugestão de como esse tipo de situação possa ser tratada, de modo que uma vez que o `textbox1` tenha o foco, independentemente de quantas vezes for pressionado <kbd>Enter</kbd>, ele execute apenas uma vez o evento `KeyDown` e passe o foco ao `textbox2`?

Código utilizado de exemplo:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {               
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");               
        }
    }        

    private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);                
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");                    
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Você já tentou colocar a seguinte linha `textbox2.Focus();` ao invés de `SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");` ? Talvez funcione.

Comment: Sim @ÉrikThiago, o problema são as várias execuções do **KeyDown** do **textbox1**. Outra situação também é de que esse foi apenas um exemplo, e não saberei qual será o próximo componente a receber o foco, a utilização do `SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")` deixa isso a cargo do aplicação pelo **TabIndex**, sendo assim obrigatório.

Comment: Coloque `SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");` antes de `Thread.Sleep(5000);`

Comment: Ele continua com o "_buffer_ do **Enter**" e assim ele executa `SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");` e `Thread.Sleep(5000);` várias vezes, tanto do **textbox1** quanto do **textbox2**

Comment: Sim irá continuar com o buffer, mas deverá estar a executar uma vez o textbox1 e depois salta para o textbox2, certo?

Comment: Sim, só que ao saltar para o **textbox2**, como temos vários **Enter** no _buffer_ ele executa o **KeyDown** do **textbox2** também, e várias vezes, logo o foco não fica necessariamente no textbox desejado.

Comment: Sim, mas isso é o comportamento esperado. Talvez haja uma possibilidade para contornar isso mas não é muito *"bonita"*. Vou colocar uma resposta para você testar.

Comment: Pensando melhor não vejo forma de distinguir um *enter* que deve ser aceite de outro ou de vários que não devem ser aceites.

Answer (score 1):

Porque não tenta encapsular como objetos, você coloca os `sendKeys.send("{TAB}")` e `Thread.Sleep` como propriedades de cada `textbox`.

Desta forma você poderá chamar o evento de forma independente, na hora que quiser e na ordem que quiser.

Answer (score 0):

Por que não simplesmente colocar uma variável de controle?
Algo como:

```
int ok1 = 0;
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (ok1 > 0) return;
        ok1++;
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
        ok2 = 0;
    }
}

int ok2 = 0;
private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (ok2 > 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        ok2++;
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
        ok1 = 0;
    }
}
```